# How to find string that occurs between 3rd and 4th instances of a character

Tags: regex, powershell

What I think I'm needing is an expression to exclude anything outside of the 3rd and 4th instances of a character, backlashes in this case. Does that sound right?

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to get the ShareName from a given UNC path in PowerShell.

Find: "Share01" in example source string:

```
\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\...
```

PowerShell's `Split-Path` is proving to be a bit limitied in this regard, and RegEx is ...hard!

Comment: As a regex, something like this: `\\\\[^\\]*\\([^\\]*)`. Escaping backslashes is annoying. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm I'm really late to this party, but I will suggest an alternative: Use the `[Uri]` type:

```
$unc = '\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\...'
$upath = [Uri]$unc
```

### Testing if the path really is a UNC path:

```
$upath.IsUnc
```

### Getting the Share

```
$upath.Segments[1]            # Returns Share01/
$upath.Segments[1].Trim('/')  # Trims the trailing /
```

## Or a one liner with no escaping or trimming:

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($unc).Split('\')[-1]
```

Comment: Nice one. That's probably the most elegant approach.

Answer (score 8):

In simple scenarios I'd use an approach similar to the one suggested by [@Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419846/1630171), but with the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of the `-split` operator to avoid regular expressions.

```
$unc = '\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\...'

$sharename = $unc.Split('\')[3]
```

If you want to be on the safe side you should canonicalize the path separators first, since PowerShell accepts both `/` and `\` as separators in a path:

```
$sharename = $unc.Replace('/', '\').Split('\')[3]
```

If you want to play it really safe there probably isn't a way around regular expressions, though, because there are a number of things to take care of:

- Ensure the path is actually a UNC path (i.e. starts with a double slash/backslash and has at least a server and share component).
- Handle both `\` and `/`.
- Handle consecutive path separators (`.//some\\\folder/\path` is a valid pathspec in PowerShell).

To handle all of this you could do the following:

```
$unc = '\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\...'
$re  = '^[\\/]{2}[^\\/]+[\\/]+([^\\/]+)'

if ($unc -match $re) {
  $sharename = $matches[1]
} else {
  "Not a valid UNC path: $unc"
}
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^[\\/]{2}` matches two consecutive slashes or backslashes at the beginning of a string.
- `[^\\/]+` matches a sequence of one or more characters that are neither slash nor backslash (i.e. a path component).
- `[\\/]+` matches consecutive path separators.
- `(...)` group a submatch (in this case the share name) so that it can be back-referenced, e.g. via the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$matches`.

Comment: Thank you! Most informative. The breakdown really helps to understand.

While i'm going with briantist's answer; for the elegant one liner; your canonisation and validation will be used too... image that's going to save much future pain

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
('\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\...' -split '\\' | ? {$_} )[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifiy this code for foud your search:

```
 $value="\\FQDN\Share01\Directories\...\...\...\..."
 $valuetosearch="Share01"
 $listresult=$value -split "\\"
 $counter = 0
 $listresult | select @{Name="Value";Expression={$_}}, @{Name="Rang";Expression={$global:counter; $global:counter++}} | where { $_.Rang -eq 3 -and $_.Value -eq $valuetosearch}
```